# Travis builds fail on dplyr vector calls within vignette

Tags: r, dplyr, travis-ci

When I push my package to travis the vignette checks fail. I'm aware I can skip it but it's bugging me.

I have identified at least one of the issues belongs to a specific call in my code.

The RMD chunk in question:

```
get_storm_data("fstadv", link = al.1998.charley %>% .$Link)
```

`al.1998.charley`:

```
al.1998.charley <- structure(list(Year = 1998, 
                                  Name = "TROPICAL STORM CHARLEY", 
                                  Basin = "AL", 
                                  Link = "http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/archive/1998/1998CHARLEYadv.html"), 
                             class = "data.frame", 
                             row.names = c(NA, -1L), 
                             .Names = c("Year", "Name", "Basin", "Link"))
```

The `link` parameter is a character string sent to the function `get_storm_data` which does some web scraping.

The following three values are identical:

```
a <- al.1998.charley %>% .$Link
b <- al.1998.charley %>% `[[`('Link')
c <- "http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/archive/1998/1998CHARLEYadv.html"
```

> identical(a, b)
>   [1] TRUE
>
> identical(b, c)
>   [1] TRUE

However, only the value `c` passed to the link parameter will pass travis.

The travis error:

```
Building with: R CMD build 
6.09s$ R CMD build  .
* checking for file ‘./DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘Hurricanes’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* installing the package to build vignettes
* creating vignettes ... ERROR
Quitting from lines 86-87 (getting-started.Rmd) 
Error: processing vignette 'getting-started.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
is.character(url) is not TRUE
Execution halted
```

All of my previous attempts to resolve this can be found [here](https://github.com/timtrice/Hurricanes/issues/24), if necessary.

**Edit**

This vignette never caused issues before. [Build 16](https://travis-ci.org/timtrice/Hurricanes/builds/215993323) passed. [Nothing was different in the vignette](https://github.com/timtrice/Hurricanes/blob/1b4cd8433e05f356d49b8b91863b9ff39ee64709/vignettes/getting-started.Rmd). I did git diff between that commit and HEAD to bring the branch to it's exact match (since original branch had since been deleted). Other than cosmetic differences in other files (spaces, newlines, etc.), it still failed.

This led me to believe it was an upgrade or change on travis' end. I read over the blog but saw no related changes between the last successful pass (Build 16) and current.

**Final Edit**

When I mentioned in the last edit the vignette had not changed since the last succesful build, I should have been more clear. That entire commit that passed in March would not pass today. I'm still not clear why.

I would like to point out for any newcomers: check the travis packages to make sure they match your system. R CMD build on my system passed with no issues. But some of my packages were outdated compared to travis'. Thanks to @jimhester (GitHub) for [pointing that out](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7701).

**Session Info**

**R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)**

**Platform:** x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

**locale:**
_LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8_, _LC_NUMERIC=C_, _LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8_, _LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8_, _LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8_, _LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8_, _LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8_, _LC_NAME=C_, _LC_ADDRESS=C_, _LC_TELEPHONE=C_, _LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8_ and _LC_IDENTIFICATION=C_

**attached base packages:** 
*stats*, *graphics*, *grDevices*, *utils*, *datasets*, *methods* and *base*

**other attached packages:** 
*Hurricanes(v.0.1.0)*, *dplyr(v.0.5.0)*, *purrr(v.0.2.2)*, *readr(v.1.0.0)*, *tidyr(v.0.6.1)*, *tibble(v.1.2)*, *ggplot2(v.2.2.1)*, *tidyverse(v.1.0.0)* and *magrittr(v.1.5)*

**loaded via a namespace (and not attached):** 
*Rcpp(v.0.12.7)*, *digest(v.0.6.10)*, *assertthat(v.0.1)*, *R6(v.2.2.0)*, *grid(v.3.4.0)*, *plyr(v.1.8.4)*, *DBI(v.0.5-1)*, *gtable(v.0.2.0)*, *scales(v.0.4.1)*, *lazyeval(v.0.2.0)*, *data.table(v.1.10.4)*, *tools(v.3.4.0)*, *pander(v.0.6.0)*, *munsell(v.0.4.3)*, *compiler(v.3.4.0)* and *colorspace(v.1.3-0)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Link` in `al.1998.charley` is stored as a factor on Travis (perhaps you have set the `stringsAsFactors` option to `FALSE` somewhere locally?). `httr` won't coerce a factor vector to character, hence you get an error. Try wrapping `as.character()` around `al.1998.charley %>% .$Link`.

Comment: Also just a small random suggestion - I wouldn't depend on R 3.4 in your package - that version just came out and if you want others to be able to use your package they would have to update to it.

Comment: that's not the issue. I should have clarified this vignette did not cause issues on the last test about a month ago. I'll update the OP. And regarding the R version; thank you for catching that. It used to be 3.2.3. Not sure why I changed it.

Comment: Chris, you turned out to be correct and thank you. I posted an issue in the travis github and a user there had responded to a little more detail - basically what you said. Apologies for discrediting you earlier. Best I can tell why one commit passed last month but not today was travis was using a newer package version; maybe curl (2.4.0 then, 2.6.0 now). This is a guess. Nonetheless, changing `data.frame` to `tibble::data_frame` worked and the full vignette passes. Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem...I thought about responding to issue on GitHub but went with this venue instead.